# How do I achieve a simple drill down hierarchy in a Table View?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

What method must I use to achieve a simple drill down data hierarchy in a UITableView, without having to add an unnecessary amount of table views in my story board? I want each cell in my master table view to transition to its own table view with its own cells when selected, and to do this without having to have multiple table views in my scene. Using SWIFT. FOR EXAMPLE:

[image: Simple Drill Down Hierarchy]

Comment: You don't have to put anything in a storyboard you don't want to. Everything that can be done in IB can also be done programmatically. Just implement tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and instantiate and present a new UITableViewController subclass. The number of subclasses you're going to need depends on how many different types of tables you need to implement.

Comment: I'm sorry should've been more clear, those labeled boxes in the diagram are all Cells in one table view. i want each cell to transition into its own table view with its own cells when selected, and those cells to transition into their own view when selected etc. does that make sense? @Dare

Comment: Yeah that's pretty standard. You need to be able to check the tableView's data source at  tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and then determine which cell was selected using indexPath.row and indexPath.section (if your tables have more than one section). If the cells are static, I would just put a switch in that method for indexPath.row and you can push whichever controller you want from there. This definitely should be done programmatically and not in a storyboard. Tracing those segues would be a total nightmare.

Comment: oh ok, thanks man, & yes that was the dilemma haha. @Dare

Comment: would i have to implement an "if" statement within the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath to determine what data to show depending on which cell is selected? @Dare

Comment: I think a switch is probably cleaner and faster. I would handle it the way @ahruss suggested in his answer. I think it's a fairly nice solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the controllers you want to transition to are as you've drawn them (i.e., you always want to segue to either A or B), you don't have to duplicate A or B; you can just have one instance each of them in the storyboard and segue to it. If the controllers you want to transition to are all the same class but need some setup before transitioning, you can implement `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)` something like this:

```
func prepareForSegue(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender sender: AnyObject) { 
    let selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)
    // set up segue.destinationViewController
}
```

If there are more classes of controllers you might want to transition to, then you can do something a little more complicated and handle selections programmatically. Override `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var vc: ViewController? = nil
    switch indexPath.row { 
        case 0: vc = ViewControllerA()
        case 1: vc = ViewControllerB()
        case 2: vc = ViewControllerC()
        ...
    } 
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry should've been more clear, those labeled boxes in the diagram are all Cells in one table view. i want each cell to transition into its own table view with its own cells when selected, and those cells to transition into their own view when selected etc. does that make sense? @ahruss

Comment: i've tried tons of variations of the switch & it crashes everytime, would i be better off using a if statement? @ahruss

Comment: @RobertTillman Were you able to find a resolution to this problem? Does switch case really work with grouped sections? Thanks!